# Can bluetooth of android device be discovered by iOS?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-device-discovery

I know we cannot transfer data between android and iOS devices through bluetooth. But, can  the iOS device scan and "see" the android bluetooth device (get the list with name of bluetooth), in both cases normal bluetooth and BLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app running on iOS cannot discover any Bluetooth 2.1/3.0 devices (excluding MFi devices for which the app is registered, which does not apply to an Android device).

If the Android device is advertising BLE/BT4.0 service(s) then an iOS app can use Core Bluetooth to discover these service(s).

Comment: Thank @Paulw11.

iOS device use CoreBluetooth to discover service(s) with special UUID. How I can get all valid bluetooth device nearby without any UUID (this look like the original "scan device" function of iOS device)

Comment: You can specify 'nil' to the CBCentralManager scan - this will return all visible devices that are advertising GATT services